# Error creating bean with name 'xxx'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm having issues with dependency injection.

I've tried both `@EJB` and `@Autowired`, but nothing works.

This is what i have now:

*HomeController*

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.vives.repositories")
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet {

    private final BeerRepository beerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public HomeController(BeerRepository beerRepository) {
        this.beerRepository = beerRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {

        List<Brewer> brewers = this.beerRepository.getAll();

        model.addAttribute("brewers", brewers);

        return "index";
    }
}
```

When I hover over beerRepository parameter, I get that:
[image]

*BeerRepository*

```
@Stateless
@Repository
public class BeerRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "vivesPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Brewer> getAll() {
        List<Brewer> brewers = new ArrayList<>();
        Brewer br0 = new Brewer("WESTVLETEREN BREWERY");
        Brewer br1 = new Brewer("BRASSERIE CANTILLON");
        Brewer br2 = new Brewer("RODENBACH BREWERY");
        Brewer br3 = new Brewer("KULMINATOR");
        Brewer br4 = new Brewer("‘T BRUGS BEERTJE");

        brewers.add(br0);
        brewers.add(br1);
        brewers.add(br2);
        brewers.add(br3);
        brewers.add(br4);
        return brewers;
    }
}
```

*persistence.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="vivesPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/beers</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

*Error log (some of it)*

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [..\HomeController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beerRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'vivesPU' available
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beerRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'vivesPU' available
...
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'vivesPU' available]]
```

vivesPU is the persistance-unit name, so why would it even go there?

*project structure*

[image]

Can someone explain to me what is happening? I'm really confused. Most of the documentation and posts are old (Spring 4 and Spring XML) which are barely relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to autowire  BeerRepository  or remove the below line

```
    private final BeerRepository beerRepository;
```

Comment: if I remove that line, i will not have a reference for the `index()` method, and if I only `Autowire` the field, I get the same notification as in the image above

Comment: Looks like its not able to create entitymanager . You need to look at the logs and check whether the hibernate jars are included in the classpath . Please paste complete logs and we can look at it

Comment: I've got the logs, but I have no idea what I'm searching for. Could you help me? There are 4 log files, each with 20k lines

Comment: Search for ' EntityManager' in the logs and paste here

Comment: After sorting and getting the unique entries, [those](https://pastebin.com/MxK0WXE7) are the only ones left

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is completely false. It should be

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.vives.repositories")
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet {

 @Autowired    
 private BeerRepository beerRepository;



    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {

        List<Brewer> brewers = beerRepository.getAll();

        model.addAttribute("brewers", brewers);

        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the message that the variable 'beerRepository' may have not been initialized

Comment: i just saw your edit, but it didn't help
[image](http://prntscr.com/hcjqmv)